# What kind of sata connector is this?

Tags: identification, connector, motherboard, sata

I have an HP motherboard that has some SATA connectors that I'm not familiar with. What kind of connector is it?

[image]

Comment: That is definitely not a SATA connector. Probably a power connector of some sort. What exactly do you want to know? The pinout, the model of the connector or what?

Comment: Are you sure you posted the right picture?

Comment: is that on the motherboard or on a power supply?

Answer (score 2):

That looks to me like a fan connector.

[Source](https://landing.coolermaster.com/faq/3-pin-and-4-pin-fan-wire-diagrams/)

Comment: It's a different connector than what's used for case and CPU fans. But I've seen that kind of connector on graphics cards and laptops.  The color scheme looks typical for a PWM fan.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

HP among others have used custom non standard cables for sata data and sata power depending on the use case.

That JST connector is likely being used for SATA power from a motherboard connector. It looks like a JST PH 4 pin 2.0mm pin to pin width. The other side is probably a molded micro sata 17 pin connector with both data and power (I'm assuming)

Comment: I should have been more specific in my post.  This is for SATA power and the other end is a 17 pin connector.  I'm just trying to find a cable.  From your response I'm looking for a JST PH 5 pin to 17 pin sata power cable. Found one https://www.amazon.com/2-0mm-Small-15Pin-Supply-Industrial/dp/B08FNW6HNJ.

Comment: @blfinche 4 pin to full size sata power? The picture you include is 4 pin not 5, and there is a difference between sata power slimline sata power and micro sata power connector sizes

Comment: @bflinche, I have the same socket on a micro-ATX industrial board, but only have open-ended with the JST PH 4 (2mm), so.... Do you know the color-coding of the cables? Based on picture on the amazon link (which shows the SATA power connector), the order should be 12V-GND-GND-5V (starting from blue on your picture), can you confirm?

Answer (score 0):

thats no kind of sata. The first SATA version supports 1.5 Gigabits/s that would not work with the cable shown in your Photograph.

Answer (score 0):

That is a [JST PH](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=199) female wire-to-wire connector housing, 2 mm pitch (as identified by [my connector identification utility](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=interior_rect_conn&u=wire_to_board_conn&o=discrete_1row_w2b_conn&f=discrete_1row_w2b_conn_2&s=PH%20%2B%20PH%20PHN%20(crimp))).

[image: JST PH connector]